# Pick Akka Streams flow to follow depending on element type

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming, akka-stream

I have a flow where I want to pick the flow to invoke on the element depending on its type. Something like:

```
sealed trait Command
case class CommandA(...) extends Command
case class CommandB(...) extends Command

private def processCommandA: Flow[CommandA, Response, NotUsed] = ???
private def processCommandB: Flow[CommandB, Response, NotUsed] = ???

def processAnyCommand: Flow[Command, Response, NotUsed] = Flow[Command]
  .flatMapConcat {
    case x: CommandA =>
      Source.single(x).via(processCommandA)

    case x: CommandB =>
      Source.single(x).via(processCommandB)
  }
```

This works, but I'm sure there must be a more elegant and efficient way to achieve this, but I'm just missing it.

I thought of building a Graph with, say, Broadcast, then have the individual `processCommandX` just ignore the commands they don't understand, then merge it together, but it's a big machinery and loses the type safety of Command being a sealed trait.

Command is a sealed trait and more implementations of it can get added so it's important for me to get the compiler's help about unhandled `case` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only able to process each `Command` type via the `processCommandA` & `processCommandB` Flows then the `flatMapConcat` technique you're using is the most direct approach.

If you have access to the functionality embedded within the two process Flows, e.g. if your Flows look like:

```
private def processFuncA(command : CommandA) = { ... }

private def processCommandA = 
  Flow[CommandA].map(processFuncA)
```

Then you can use a basic [Flow#map](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow@map[T](f:Out=%3ET):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]) method:

```
def processAnyCommand = 
  Flow[Command] map { _ match {
      case a : CommandA => processFuncA(a)
      case b : CommandB => processFuncB(b)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks.They are proper flows which invoke more flows. Transforming them into functions would require materializing them for no good reason.